# Protecting specific folder/path (Web Service) with Basic Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis, basic-authentication

So I have this C# / ASP.NET 4.5 web application that runs on a specific URL ( www.someurl.com ). This application is worked on locally, and using Visual Studio's "Publish Web App" feature gets deployed to test and production servers (Windows 2012 R2 and IIS 8.5). All fine and dandy. On the production server, SSL is applied so the application runs on HTTPS.

Now, a new Web Service has been added to the web application and is placed in a (sub-)folder in said web application as is the case with other web services that are already running. Usually I would secure a web service using OAUTH(2) or similar methods. However, the client consuming the web service has, due to limitations in their programming, requested for Basic Authentication for security.

I can't for the life of me seem to figure out how to get this running. I created a new user account on the server, enabled Basic Authentication in IIS, used "Convert to application" on the folder the web service resides in and when I go to www.someurl.com/folder/to/some/webservice.asmx it indeed asks for my credentials. However, the ASMX file, which is a marker file since the web application gets published to this server, will be treated as a non-functional marker file and return a server error (`The page must have a <%@ webservice class="MyNamespace.MyClass" ... %> directive.`)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess I'd start by checking the App Pool configuration (including its ASP.NET version)

Comment: All application pools are (standard) .NET 4.0 with Integrated pipeline mode. The application pool configured for the folder which is converted to an application, is the same application pool the 'main' web application runs in. Whether I make separate application pools or use Classis pipeline mode, doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stumbling on the same issue: I got what I wanted using a `<location>` tag in my main Web.Config file, disregarding the conversion to application in IIS at folder level:

```
<location path="folder/to/some/webservice">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```